# add subview loaded from a nib into a frame

Tags: iphone, uiview

I want to add a view from a nib file as a subview of my main view at the click of a button, but it has to be in a frame (0,108,320,351). I've tried the following code:

```
-(IBAction) displayJoinmeetup:(id)sender  
{  
  [meetups removeFromSuperview]; //removing the older view   
  CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 108,320,351);  
  [joinmeetup initWithFrame:myFrame];  //joinmeetup declared in header file as IBoutlet UIView*joinmeetup     
  [self.view addSubview:joinmeetup];    
}
```

This displays only a blank screen, otherwise if I remove the frame the subview displays covering the whole screen, how can I properly do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never call init... on an object after it has been created. If you can change a setting, there will be a setter for it. In this case, it is setFrame:

```
-(IBAction) displayJoinmeetup:(id)sender {  
    [meetups removeFromSuperview]; //removing the older view   
    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 108,320,351);  
    [joinmeetup setFrame:myFrame];  //joinmeetup declared in header file as IBoutlet UIView*joinmeetup     
    [self.view addSubview:joinmeetup];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

initWithFrame is not called for a view loaded from nib.  See the UIView class ref for details.
You need to set the view size properties in interface builder (inspector).

Answer (score 0):

You can try thi as follow:

```
-(IBAction) displayJoinmeetup:(id)sender
{
if(meetups)
{
[meetups removeFromSuperview]; //removing the older view
//also here you should release the meetups, if it is allocated
meetups = nil;
}

UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 108,320,351)];
joinmeetup = tempView;
[tempView release];
[self.view addSubview:joinmeetup];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this:

```
[joinmeetup setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 108,320,351)];
[self.view addSubview:joinmeetup];
```

Comment: frame is a property declared in UIView